# C# Displaying a Class Variable that is stored in an Array

Tags: c#, arrays, class, listbox

I will try to simplify this down as much as I can to make this as understandable as I can.
I have created various classes (to be known as **Person1**, **Person2** and **Person3**)
each of which has their own variables (examples being **Name**, **Age** and **ID**).
I created a one dimesional array which will be called **PeopleArray** with a maximum amount of 10 entries held in the array, each of these hold an instance of one of the Classes.

Note: when the form is loaded entries are made into the array and assigns values to each of the appropriate variables

I then created a Listbox called **ListOfPeople** which allows the user to select from the entries in the array.
What I want to do is take one of the Variables from the appropriate Classes and display the value held by it in a label.

For this lets say I have in the Array at position [0], the entry is of the Person1 Class and I want to find the value of the "Name" variable.
What would be the code to display that in a label.
"Label.Text = "

Note: what I would want the code to do however is account for whichever entry is selected, a method in the form of my previous example will suffice and I will work from there.

Any help you can give is much appriciated. Thank You

Comment: WPF ? WinForms? If WPF, it's rather simple, and I can post some code a bit later. Winforms shouldn't be too different.

Answer (score 0):

WPF solution:

Assuming properties on the viewmodel:

```
public List<ListBoxPersonExample> ListBoxItems { get; set; }

public ListBoxPersonExample SelectedPerson
{
    get { return _selectedPerson; }
    set { _selectedPerson = value; RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedPerson");}
}
```

Where the class `ListBoxPersonExample` is defined as:

```
public class ListBoxPersonExample
{
    public ListBoxPersonExample(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "My name is :" + Name;
    }
}
```

This XAML will do what you need:

```
<Grid>
     <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
     </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <ListBox Name="ListBoxName" ItemsSource="{Binding ListBoxItems}" 
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPerson}"></ListBox>
        <Label Grid.Column="1" Content="{Binding SelectedPerson.Name}"></Label>
 </Grid>
```